# Get the last className but not the one specified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've googled for this issue but really didn't find any help regarding this.

I've div which has 3 classes. I want to get the last className but not the one I specify.

E.x third is last class in the div but I  do not want that to be selected except in this case I want the second last one to be selected.

So far I've tried

```
 $('div:not(.third)').attr('class').split(' ').pop();//Throwing Type Error

$('div').attr('class').split(' ').pop().not(".third");//.not is not a function
```

I've made simple fiddle for that If any buddy could help me out.

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/h67zhLzL/

Comment: Well, something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1c0yvp7/), I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) does remove the last element, but it also returns the element which was removed. You just need to access the original array:

```
$("button").on("mouseenter",function(){
    var arr = $("div").attr('class').split(' '); // Split the class into the array
    arr.pop(); // Remove the last element
    // Make sure we're left with at least one class
    if(arr.length) console.log(arr[arr.length-1]);  // Prints "second"
});
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/91fu3ypa/)

Comment: I don't have any concern weather it removes it or not but I want the classname that is not third.

var yourlastclass =  arr.pop();
console.log(yourlastclass is third);

Comment: @user2736704 No problem, updated answer. Just need to access the last index of the array

Comment: sorry that was just fine Thanks

Comment: Usage of `.attr('class').split(' ')` is not actually safe. `<div class="first second third ">div</div>` (there is space between `third` and `"`) will ruin logic of your code.

Comment: @Regent True. `$("div")[0].classList` would be preferable, but hey, that wasn't the OP's question :)

Comment: Trim the string and split by `/\s+/`.

Comment: @RGraham I still don't understand what the question is really about. If the idea is to take the last class of element, but the last means "we go from the end of element's classes and take first one that not equals to _excluded class_", then all answers are not correct. But this answer is accepted one. So "yes" - if OP is satisfied, let it be so :)

Comment: @Regent I took it to mean the second-last class, but reading your comment again it certainly sounds like the "last class if we remove `third`" - in which case you're right, this isn't the correct solution. I'm sure they'll find that out and as a new question if required :)

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you want to get the last item of an array, except it has a value you specified before:

```
var classes = $("div").attr('class').split(' ');
classes.pop();
var index = classes.indexOf('third');
if(index > -1){        
    classes.splice(index, 1);
}
var lastclass = classes.pop();
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5uf02efv/)**

**Reference**

[.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

[.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correct, this is your solution.

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
    var arr = $("div").attr('class').split(' ');

    alert(arr[arr.length -2]); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g495r038/1/